# Using a list I created within the constructor of a class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object, methods, constructor

Why does it say I can't add "int and grade" in the get_average() method when I try to run it? I know it has to probably to do because they are two different types, but I am just wondering how to fix it.

Ultimately with my question I am just wondering on how to fix my code, so I can add the person's grades to a list and then either average them, or show them, and I am struggling with how to do it.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = []

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if type(grade) == Grade:
            self.grades.append(grade)
            return self.grades

    def get_average(self):
        gradebook = self.grades
        total = 0
        for grade in gradebook:
            total += int(grade)
        avg = total / len(gradebook)
        return avg

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{p} has these grades: {g}".format(p=self.name, g=self.grades)

# student1 = Student()
# student1.attendance = {
#   "11/1/98": True,
#   "11/2/98": False 
# }

roger = Student("Roger van der Weyden", 10)
sandro = Student("Sandro Botticelli", 12)
pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder", 8)

class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65

    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def is_passing(self):
        if self.score > self.minimum_passing:
            return "{p} is passing with a grade of {g}".format(p=pieter.get_name(), g=self.score)

# Checking for grades and averages
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
#print(pieter.get_average())
print(pieter)

# Tells you if the dude is passing
# roger_grade = Grade(100)
# print(roger_grade.is_passing())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Student class, you have a list of grades which contain `Grade` object.
When you run `get_average()` it attempts to do the following `total += int(grade)`. This fails because you are trying to cast an object to int.

You need to pass in the int value of the grade which can be accessed by `grade.score`

Similarly you need to change `def __repr__(self):` to print out actual grades instead of address of grade object.

Here is the fixed code.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = []

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if type(grade) == Grade:
            self.grades.append(grade)
            return self.grades

    def get_average(self):
        gradebook = self.grades
        total = 0
        for grade in gradebook:
            total += int(grade.score)
        avg = total / len(gradebook)
        return avg

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{p} has these grades: {g}".format(p=self.name, g=[sc.score for sc in self.grades])

# student1 = Student()
# student1.attendance = {
#   "11/1/98": True,
#   "11/2/98": False 
# }

roger = Student("Roger van der Weyden", 10)
sandro = Student("Sandro Botticelli", 12)
pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder", 8)

class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65

    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def is_passing(self):
        if self.score > self.minimum_passing:
            return "{p} is passing with a grade of {g}".format(p=pieter.get_name(), g=self.score)

# Checking for grades and averages
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(0))


print(pieter.get_average())
print(pieter)

# Tells you if the dude is passing
# roger_grade = Grade(100)
# print(roger_grade.is_passing())
```